# Using a shared file as a tunnel (socat ?)

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to proxify a Citrix connexion. As you may know, you can have shared file under Citrix ICA (shared between the client and the server), and I'd like to use this possibility to mount a "tunnel" between the 2.

The idea would be to have the following :

```
                   on the client side )
any program => 'in' => shared file(s) => 'out' => remote network
                      ( on the server side
```

Any idea how to do this? It seems to me that socat should be able to do the trick, I'm diving into its man right now, but can't figure out everything yet.

Thanks for any input.

For the moment I'm stuck with :

On one side:

```
socat -x -v -d -d tcp-listen:10002,fork,reuseaddr gopen:read.txt!!write.txt
```

On the other side:

```
socat -x -v -d -d gopen:write.txt!!read.txt tcp-connect:www.google.com:80
```

however, this doesnt work at all: cmd1 fails when connecting in (unknown device/address "write.txt") and cmd2 fails at launch (unknown device/address "read.txt")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this little very nice tools that does the job nicely : https://labs.withsecure.com/tools/tcp-over-file-tunnel

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to a remote host on ssh from the citrix server, I would suggest to launch a socks proxy and then set up a ssh tunnel with a remote port forward.

Comment: Actually no, the CITRIX is totally isolated from other network and the ICA connection is the only thing allowed in by the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a program called [File Tunnel](https://github.com/fiddyschmitt/file_tunnel) which can be used to tunnel TCP over a shared file.

It supports both Windows and Linux.